# Attempting to SELECT, reduce by 1 then UPDATE with php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Just trying to find a Value of a table field and then reduce it by one using MySQL via PHP?

Is there an simple way to do this?

Below code will not process...

Cheers, J

```
<?php   
$conn = connectToDB();
/* DECLARE remaining AS INTEGER  */
settype($screenings, "integer"); 
/* SELECT CURRENT screenings VALUE AND ASSIGN TO remaining VARIABLE */
$findquery("SELECT screenings FROM screener_users WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "';");
$screenings = $conn->query($findquery); 
/* REDUCE THAT VALUE BY ONE */
$screenings--;
/* UPDATE screener_users WITH THAT NEW VALUE */
$updatequery = "UPDATE screener_users SET screenings = '" . $screenings . "' WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "';";
$result = $conn->query($updatequery);
?>
```

Comment: lose the comments man n format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a mistake on query call. As you can see at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php) , it returns an PDOStatement, so you should call a resultset to get the value that you want. Something like this should work:

```
<?php   
$conn = connectToDB();
settype($screenings, "integer"); 
$findquery("SELECT screenings FROM screener_users WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "';");
foreach ($conn->query($findquery) as $row)
{
    $screenings = $row[0];
    $screenings--;        
    $updatequery = "UPDATE screener_users SET screenings = '" . $screenings . "' WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "';";
    $result = $conn->query($updatequery);
}
?>
```

Now you are calling the query to be executed and saying that it should get the resultset of wich row and assing it to `$row` while iterating over it. There, you call the first column of the query's return (`$row[0]`) and do the rest of the job.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to do it in one command:

```
"UPDATE screener_users SET screenings = screenings - 1 WHERE user_id = '$userId'"
```

By the way, you're open for SQL injection. Take advantage of prepared statements and parameter binding for the user_id.